# EntityFramework Code First self-referencing one to one (1:1) relationship mapping - Unable to determine the principal end

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, self-reference

I have this class:

```
public class Message
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public virtual Message ParentMessage { get; set; }

    public virtual Message ChildMessage { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

Using `EntityFramework` `Code First` `Add-Migration` gives me the message: `Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types...`

I can't use the `[Required]` attribute, because the first message in this thread will have no parent, the last message in the thread will have no child... how do I map this?

I tried:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.ParentMessage);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.ChildMessage);
```

but that did not work.

Comment: Serj - I misread your question and deleted my post. Sorry for the bad info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found something that looks like it could be it, if someone could verify that this is correct:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<SecureMessage>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.ParentMessage)
            .WithOptionalDependent(x => x.ChildMessage);
```

So after some serious testing, this does indeed seem to be the solution.